# Chrome extension: EventListener not working despite no error

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

Unlike other similar posts where they had code issues ([SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426079/chrome-extension-not-loading-eventlistener), [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39437670/javascript-eventlistener-not-working)), I am no longer getting a

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

as I am using `document.onload()` so their solution didn't help

My code:

popup.html

```
<button class="submit" id='checkButton'>
      Submit
    </button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./content.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/background.js"></script>
```

Background.js

```
function submit(){
  alert('loaded')
}
document.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("checkButton").addEventListener("click", submit);
  console.log('loaded')
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "To be named",
    "description": "This extension helps...",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "browser_action":{
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "identity",
        "identity.email",
        "http://127.0.0.1:5000/test",
        "http://127.0.0.1:5000/get/info",
        "http://127.0.0.1:5000/test",
        "http://0.0.0.0:5000/test",
        "http://127.0.0.1:5000/Time"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },  
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["https://www.blank.org/"], 
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "css": ["styles.css"]
    }]
}
```

Yet, when I click on submit from extension. I don't get any 'loaded' (same applies if I move func to content.js) nor do I get any error in my chrome://extemsion as mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert, but I think the problem is your trying to edit the popup.html DOM from a background script. That won't work. Instead try this:

background.js:

```
//Your other javascript...
var views = chrome.extension.getViews({
type: "popup"
});
for (var i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
views[i].document.getElementById('checkButton').addEventListener("click", submit);
console.log("loaded");
}
```

I'm assuming this as if you were using the background.js as a background script. I don't see why you're including background.js in the bottom of popup.html, though. Here's what I suggest:

popup.html:

```
<button class="submit" id='checkButton'>
      Submit
</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./popup.js"></script>
```

popup.js:

```
function submit(){
  alert('loaded')
}
document.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("checkButton").addEventListener("click", submit);
  console.log('loaded')
}
```

Hope this works! :)